# How to create nested weighted distributions in Python/numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, montecarlo

I am trying to optimize (vectorize?) the creation of a monte-carlo style simulation and I have not been able to figure out how to create nested-weighted random values using `numpy` or similar libraries.  Consider the scenario, inspired by an `interviewqs` question: "Students in three classrooms have to vote for one of two class president candidates.  Classroom A has 40% of the students and are split 50/50 on candidate X and Y.  B has 25% of the students and is split 60/40.  C has 35% of the students and is split 35/65"

Creating that data with vanilla Python might look something like this,

```py
import random

nsimulations = 10_000_000

def choose_classroom():
    "returns A, B, or C based on percentages"
    value = random.random()
    if value < .4:
        return 'A'
    elif value < .65:
        return 'B'
    else:
        return 'C'
        
def choose_support(classroom):
    "return X or Y based on support percentage by classroom"
    value = random.random()
    if classroom == 'A':
        return "X" if value < .5 else "Y"
    elif classroom == 'B':
        return "X" if value < .6 else "Y"
    elif classroom == 'C':
        return "X" if value < .35 else "Y"
        
results = []
for i in range(nsimulations):
    classroom = choose_classroom()
    support = choose_support(classroom)
    results.append({'classroom': classroom, 'support': support})
```

It takes about 10 seconds to run the 10M simulations on my machine.  I'd like to improve that time.  The first thing I looked at was [numpy.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), `fast_classrooms = np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], size=nsimulations, p=[.4, .25, .35])`.  That does execute quickly, about 350ms.  However I don't know how to generate the follow-on `X`/`Y` distributions from there.

One thing I've tried is Pandas `apply`, and it seems like it is doing some kind of optimizations under the covers.  The below Pandas snippet takes ~2.5 seconds to run while a list comprehension (`[choose_support(record) for record in fast_classrooms]` takes ~4 seconds.  Still, it feels like this isn't the "right" way to do things.

```py
import pandas
import numpy as np

fast_classrooms = np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], size=nsimulations, p=[.4, .25, .35])
df = pandas.DataFrame({'classroom': fast_classrooms})
df['support'] = df.classroom.apply(choose_support)
```

What I had hoped to find is something that could generate nested weighted distributions, something like - `np.random.choice([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['X', 'Y']], p=[[.4, .25, .35], [[.5, .5], [.6, .4], [.35, .65]]])`

What are some ways of going about generating this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can significantly reduce the number of python looping, making the code more vectorized:

```
import numpy as np

nsimulations = 12
uniquerooms = ['A','B','C']
supportprobs = [0.5, 0.6, 0.35]
classrooms = np.random.choice(uniquerooms, size=nsimulations, p=[.4, .25, .35])
supports = np.empty_like(classrooms, dtype=classrooms.dtype)
for room, prob in zip(uniquerooms, supportprobs):
    mask = classrooms == room
    supports[mask] = np.random.choice(['X','Y'], size=mask.sum(), p=[prob, 1-prob])

print(classrooms)
# ['C' 'A' 'C' 'A' 'C' 'C' 'A' 'C' 'B' 'C' 'B' 'A']
print(supports)
# ['X' 'Y' 'Y' 'Y' 'Y' 'X' 'Y' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'Y' 'X']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.random.choice` on the pairs instead of running the function twice. Meaning that you can calculate the probability of having a pair ('classroom', 'support'). For example, the probability of choosing classroom 'A' AND get support 'X' is 0.4*0.5 = 0.2, and so on.

The code below works quite fast for me.

```
import numpy as np
nsimulations = 10000000

#Construct the probabilities and pairs 
p = [.4*.5, .4*.5, .25*.6, .25*.4, .35*.35, .35*.65]
pairs = [{'classroom': 'A', 'support': 'X'}, 
         {'classroom': 'A', 'support': 'Y'},
         {'classroom': 'B', 'support': 'X'},
         {'classroom': 'B', 'support': 'Y'},
         {'classroom': 'C', 'support': 'X'},
         {'classroom': 'C', 'support': 'Y'}]

# Sample the pairs based on the probabilities
fast_classrooms = np.random.choice(pairs, size=nsimulations, p=p)
```

EDIT:

This code took `0.6193864345550537 seconds` compared to the method posted by OP with `7.815439224243164 seconds`. Also confirmed by @Tom McLean in the comment.

Comment: This was the way I was thinking but couldnt think of a way of implementing it

Comment: This is such an elegant answer! I would like to add that one can use `itertools.product` to get the cartesian product (the combinations of `X` and `Y` and the probabilities), in case one has too many pairs to type by hand.

Comment: @iffanh I really like this answer, it's so clever!  Is there a fast way to read an ndarray of dictionaries into pandas, so that `classroom` and `support` are in their own columns?   `pandas.DataFrame(fast_classrooms)` executes quickly but gives me a single column of dictionaries.  Trying `DataFrame(fast_classrooms.tolist())` or `DataFrame.from_records(fast_classroom)` splits it out into columns but takes several seconds

Comment: For reference this method took 0.42s on my machine for 10M simulations vs 7.7s from the method in the question

Comment: @Kafonek glad that you like the answer. For the follow up question, you can do the following (though I am not sure if it's any better than yours):

`tuples = [(pair['classroom'], pair['support']) for pair in fast_classrooms]; classroom_list, support_list = zip(*tuples); df = pd.DataFrame({'classroom': classroom_list, 'support': support_list})`

This perhaps is not the best way to do it, since here we are basically looping over the list again. The best way might be to have the structure right from the beginning, instead of {'classroom':A, 'support':X}.

Comment: @iffanh Just for completeness sake, consider to add a time benchmark comparison with the OP working solution

Comment: @FBruzzesi Thanks for the suggestion. Added :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the current top answer is the most elegant, but I want to throw [numpy.piecewise](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) into the mix due to the extendibility of the conditionals:

```py
import numpy as np 

fast_classrooms = np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], size=nsimulations, p=[.4, .25, .35])

np.piecewise(fast_classrooms, [fast_classrooms == 'A', fast_classrooms =='B', fast_classrooms=='C'], 
             [lambda X: "X" if np.random.random() < .5 else "Y",
              lambda X: "X" if np.random.random() < .6 else "Y",
              lambda X: "X" if np.random.random() < .35 else "Y"
             ])

out: array(['X', 'X', 'Y', ..., 'Y', 'X', 'X']
```

~660ms on 10mil simulations on my machine, YMMV

Comment: Thanks @Michael Karman.  I think `np.random.random()` might be calculated just a single time in your lambda functions.  When I read in `fast_classrooms` and `out` to a DataFrame, all of the `A`'s have the same `X` or `Y` value, etc.